# Best practice for hiding functionality from users?

Tags: android

I have an advanced settings page that I want only power users / administrators to know about and have access to.

I was thinking doing something like bringing up the settings activity when the user performed some kind of 'secret' gesture, like tapping on a certain part of the screen (Action Bar?) 5 times.

Are there any other, simple, established ways of hiding functionality from users like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about different roles for different users? Depending on the role you can offer advanced functionality or not.

Comment: How you are recognizing which user is power and which one is administrator?

Comment: @mirco.widmer Thanks for the suggestion. I'm presuming that the role is define by getting the user to login. I'm not sure this would work for me as I want an ultra-lightweight app, and presenting the user with a login screen would cause more friction that I'd like. Maybe I could have a way of interrupting the app startup sequence to reveal an optional admin login screen.

Comment: @BharatSharma - not sure if the comment was address to me or mirco.widmer, but I'm treating power users and administrator as one group. The other group is 'regular' users.

Comment: How about an updating secret code... which they can get from your site only...

Comment: There should be some data attached with admin user you cant rely on simple touch or gesture for the admin user. So you can use the data with physical activities. So first thing is your data if data is admin then you can display your admin setting by asking any password which you can encrypt else if data is not admin or password is wrong you can simply display basic setting.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I'm currently use in my project is to define some broadcast receiver with secret Intent's action and for additional security with password in Intent's bundle.

So when `onReceive(Intent)` happens I set preference `ADVANCED_MODE` to true;

For sending this intent you can use this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.cwfk.ig88.intents&hl=uk

Comment: thanks - interesting approach. Just to check my understanding ... you send the intent from an external app, which prompts the original app to display a hidden menu item?

Answer (score 0):

The tapping something a few times is done by android itself too for hiding the development settings, but I think the most established method is just showing them but adding very clear warnings that these settings are not for average users.

Also, the Android design document from Google might be helpful to you: http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Comment: thanks. I want the screen to be ultra lightweight, so I'm really keen to avoid buttons that regular users aren't going to need (if possible)